# How to use zingchart with ng-repeat so i can show different data on different charts. Is there any way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, zingchart

> The array is

```
array = [{
    humidity: 100
    , max_temp: 289.48
    , min_temp: 288.597
    , pressure: 1005.27
    , sea_level: 1030.68
}
, {
    humidity: 84
    , max_temp: 300.73
    , min_temp: 298.697
    , pressure: 1026.02
    , sea_level: 1026.67
}]
```

> Code in HTML is

```
<div class="chart" ng-repeat="obj in array">
            <div id="resizable">
                <div zingchart zc-values="myValues" zc-json="myJson" zc-width="100%" zc-height="100%"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="chartinfo">
                <li>0 : Humidity {{obj.humidity}}</li>
                <li>1 : Maximum Temprature {{obj.max_temp}}</li>
                <li>2 : Minimum Temprature {{obj.min_temp}}</li>
                <li>3 : Pressure {{obj.pressure}}</li>
                <li>4 : Sea Level {{obj.sea_level}}</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

> The data in the ul li should be display on the chart. what should i do to do it.
>   what to do on controller part

Comment: Did you check the examples and documentation @ https://www.zingchart.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found the solution.
>
> The zc-value take array in it so if an array is passed to it. then it work correctly.
>
> So for this convert your array in the array of arrays and pass it to ng-repeat and pass object of array to zc-value.
>
> The array should be :

array = [[100, 289.48, 288.597, 1005.27, 1030.68],[84, 300.73, 298.697, 1026.02, 1026.67]];

> And the code in html should be

```
<div class="chart" ng-repeat="obj in array">
        <div id="resizable">
            <div zingchart zc-values="obj" zc-json="myJson" zc-width="100%" zc-height="100%"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="chartinfo">
            <li>0 : Humidity {{obj[0]}}</li>
            <li>1 : Maximum Temprature {{obj[1]}}</li>
            <li>2 : Minimum Temprature {{obj[2]}}</li>
            <li>3 : Pressure {{obj[3]}}</li>
            <li>4 : Sea Level {{obj[4]}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```